# TabGroupActivity - startChildActivity - not working

Tags: android, android-tabhost, android-tabactivity

I have been using `TabActivity` and I want the tab to display on every child activity. I have flow like this `MainActivity(TabActivity)` -> `TabGroupActivity1(TabGroupActivity)` -> `Activity1` -> `Activity2`

Now i want to redirect on Activity2 only if the flag is true. so that my code for that is something like bellow.

```
TabGroupActivity

    public class TabGroupActivity extends ActivityGroup {

    private ArrayList<String> mIdList;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);       
        if (mIdList == null) mIdList = new ArrayList<String>();
    }

    /**
     * This is called when a child activity of this one calls its finish method. 
     * This implementation calls {@link LocalActivityManager#destroyActivity} on the child activity
     * and starts the previous activity.
     * If the last child activity just called finish(),this activity (the parent),
     * calls finish to finish the entire group.
     */
  @Override
  public void finishFromChild(Activity child) {
      LocalActivityManager manager = getLocalActivityManager();
      int index = mIdList.size()-1;

      if (index < 1) {
          finish();
          return;
      }

      manager.destroyActivity(mIdList.get(index), true);
      mIdList.remove(index); index--;
      String lastId = mIdList.get(index);
      Intent lastIntent = manager.getActivity(lastId).getIntent();
      Window newWindow = manager.startActivity(lastId, lastIntent);
      setContentView(newWindow.getDecorView());
  }

  /**
   * Starts an Activity as a child Activity to this.
   * @param Id Unique identifier of the activity to be started.
   * @param intent The Intent describing the activity to be started.
   * @throws android.content.ActivityNotFoundException.
   */
  public void startChildActivity(String Id, Intent intent) {     
      Window window = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity(Id,intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));
      if (window != null) {
          mIdList.add(Id);
          setContentView(window.getDecorView()); 
      }    
  }

  /**
   * The primary purpose is to prevent systems before android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.ECLAIR
   * from calling their default KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK during onKeyDown.
   */
  @Override
  public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
      if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
          //preventing default implementation previous to android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.ECLAIR
          return true;
      }
      return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
  }

  /**
   * Overrides the default implementation for KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK 
   * so that all systems call onBackPressed().
   */
  @Override
  public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
      if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
          onBackPressed();
          return true;
      }
      return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
  }

  /**
   * If a Child Activity handles KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK.
   * Simply override and add this method.
   */
  @Override
  public void  onBackPressed  () {
      int length = mIdList.size();
      if ( length > 1) {
          Activity current = getLocalActivityManager().getActivity(mIdList.get(length-1));
          current.finish();
      }  
  }
}
```

now code for `TabGroupActvity1`

```
public class TabGroupActyvity1 extends TabGroupActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        startChildActivity("OptionsActivity", new Intent(this,Activity1.class));
    }


}
```

now in `Activity1`

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if(flag){
            TabGroupActivity parentActivity = (TabGroupActivity)getParent();
            Intent previewMessage = new Intent(parentActivity, Activity2.class);
            parentActivity.startChildActivity("Activity2", previewMessage);
        }else{
            setContentView(R.layout.row);
            //... 
        }
    }
```

this is not working,

the same code the one in bellow works in some click event but not working in my case

```
TabGroupActivity parentActivity = (TabGroupActivity)getParent();
Intent previewMessage = new Intent(parentActivity, Activity2.class);
parentActivity.startChildActivity("Activity2", previewMessage);
```

please give some suggestion how to do this.
have I explain the problem well... do I need to add some more details?

Comment: if(flag)... flag contains what? where you initialize it.

Comment: flag is for login if user is login it will true it will come from the class which extends the Application class and the debugger also goes in the if part but it is not showing the Activity2

Comment: Just check my example and code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, I found other alternative.

Instead of...
checking flag in the child activity and redirecting on different page.

I am checking the flag in the parnt activity Like this

```
if (getLNApplication().isLogin()) {
    startChildActivity("Report", new Intent(this, ReportActivity.class));
}else{
    startChildActivity("LogIn", new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class));
}
```

and from `LoginActivity` on Successful login i am Starting `ReportActivity` like bellow

```
parentActivity.startChildActivity("EditActivity", new Intent(getParent(), ReportActivity.class));
```

and I also handle the back press as of I don't want user to go back on login page again. I handle the back key in `TabGroupActivity`

like this

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    int length = mIdList.size();
    if (length > 1) {
        Activity current = getLocalActivityManager().getActivity(
                mIdList.get(length - 1));
        // Added code to disable back press only for the ReportActivity
        if(current instanceof ReportActivity){
            Log.i("TabGroup", "I am instance of ReportActivity" );
            return;
        }
        current.finish();
    }
}
```